# Why am I getting NullPointterException using PDField.setValue() from PDFBox 2.0.19?

Tags: nullpointerexception, pdfbox, setvalue

I am trying to change text in a field of a PDF file but keep getting NullPointerException. I'm using PDFBox 2.0.19.

The file is loading fine, I'm able to for example add a page and save a new one on Desktop, but setting filed's value keeps crashing.

Can you help me please? What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Bondi/Desktop/karta.pdf");
    PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDDocumentCatalog pdDocumentCatalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdDocumentCatalog.getAcroForm();
    if (pdAcroForm != null) {
        PDField pdField = (PDField) pdAcroForm.getField("imie_badacza");
        pdField.setValue("Badacz");
    }
    pdDocument.save("C:/Users/Bondi/Desktop/karta2.pdf");
    pdDocument.close();
}
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpTpW.png):[image]

[My pdf's fields hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGKSA.png):[image]

Comment: Pdfield is null. Can you share the PDF?

Comment: Alternatively start PDFDebugger and hover over the field to see the name

Answer (score 1):

You should use the fully qualified field name. I.e. instead of

```java
PDField pdField = (PDField) pdAcroForm.getField("imie_badacza");
```

use

```java
PDField pdField = (PDField) pdAcroForm.getField("topmostSubform.Page1.imie_badacza");
```